# How to get Google drive file by folder name or folder ID?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am using Google Apis client lib.

I do not understand how to get file list based on folder name or folder id like:-

Drive Folder Structure

```
Main =>
    - Demo 1
        - img.png
        - img2.png
    - Demo 2
        - img_Demo 2.png
        - img2_Demo 2.png
    - Demo 3
        - img_Demo 3.png
        - img2_Demo 3.png
```

Now I get Main folder list and id using below code

```
<?php
// include your composer dependencies
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
#https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

$client->setAccessToken('AccessToken');

$drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$files_list = $drive->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles($optParams);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($files_list);
exit;
?>
```

I got this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile Object
        (
            [id] => 1LKMiCuI3OlUYrFlQnl
            [imageMediaMetadataType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata
            [imageMediaMetadataDataType:protected] => 
            [isAppAuthorized] => 
            [kind] => drive#file
            [lastModifyingUserType:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_User
            [mimeType] => application/vnd.google-apps.folder
            [name] => main
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File.list has the q paramater which will allow you to [search](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-parameters) files.   The following would return all files that have a parent id of 1234567 that being the file id of the directory you wish to find.

```
'1234567' in parents
```

You can send the q param as part of your optParams

```
$optParams = array( 'q' => "'1234567' in parents" ); 
$files_list = $drive->files->listFiles($optParams);
```

Comment: How Can I do that? Is there any function to this?

Comment: $optParams = array(
        'q' => "1LKMiCuI3qNCMsdsfdfsW0EspsNFCOlUYrFlQnl"
        );
$files_list = $drive->files->listFiles($optParams);

Comment: check my edit it should be more like that  try testing it out on this page you can play with the  q parameter on the left https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Comment: You save my day. Thank you

Comment: @DaImTo, how to get files using multiple folderids at once. Lets say I have 20 folderIds and I want to get all files from those folders only.

Comment: you can&#39;t .  your going to have to search each folder one at a time

Comment: How I can get folder Id by it's name?

Comment: do a file.list with the q parameter specific the name of the file you are looking for